# How do I remove rows on duplicated ids?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | value 1 |
| 00001 | value 2 |
| 00002 | value 3 |
| 00003 | value 4 |
| 00004 | value 5 |
| 00004 | value 6 |

What I want to do is remove it so that I am left with this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | value 1 |
| 00002 | value 3 |
| 00003 | value 4 |
| 00004 | value 5 |

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to remove duplicates using only first row as criteria, you can using following code

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID"], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ID` is just a column and not the index

```
df.drop_duplicates('ID', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yep, it is a column and not the index, solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep="first")`